# Estimate mean and standard deviation of a population

Tags: normal-distribution

I have run Shapiro-Wilk normality test on an 80 value sample and the output was a p-value of 0.001137.

Now I would like to know what are the parameters of the gaussian function that best describes my sample. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding but such a $p$ value might be suggesting the data may *not* be normal (e.g. see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15696/interpretation-of-shapiro-wilk-test) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test)).

But, in any case, if you want to fit a Gaussian distribution to the data $\{x_k\}_{j=1}^n$, the easiest way is estimate the mean and variance by
$$
\bar{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i\;\;\;\;\&\;\;\;\;s^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i (x_i-\bar{x})^2
$$
and use the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\bar{x},s^2)$.

Comment: You are right. I terribly misunderstood Shapiro-Wilk test. However, is this the only way to fit a gaussian distribution to data ? I have heard that there are other methods that are "more precise".

Comment: @Mohamed7 For a single Gaussian, I'm not sure you can really do much better than this (let me know if you find a way to do so). But, for harder distributions (like Gaussian mixture models) it can be better to do, say, EM.